# Python sum list elements according to other list

Tags: python, list

I have this two lists :

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
y = [1.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.9, 2.5, 3.1, 1.4]
```

I want to sum y elements according to every duplicate element in x.

For example, for the first element of x **(=1)**, I will have to sum all y elements at indexs **0, 3 and 4** which are indexs of **1** in x. I want to save the element and its sum.

My output will be like this :

```
sum = [[1, 5.7],
       [2, 3.6],
       [3, 2.1]]
```

How can I code this ?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: As a general attack, look up `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a one-liner:

```
>>> [[x_num, sum([y_num for i, y_num in enumerate(y) if x[i] == x_num])] for x_num in set(x)]
[[1, 5.7], [2, 3.6], [3, 2.0999999999999996]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)
for k,v in zip(x,y):
    d[k] += v

list(map(list, d.items()))
# [[1, 5.7], [2, 3.6], [3, 2.0999999999999996]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
y = [1.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.9, 2.5, 3.1, 1.4]
d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in groupby(sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda x:x[1]), key=lambda x:x[1])]
result = [[a, sum(y[k] for k, _ in b)] for a, b in d]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5.7], [2, 3.6], [3, 2.0999999999999996]]
```